# Laravel Dependent Selects

Tags: javascript, sql-server, ajax, laravel

I've been struggling with this for several days. I have to select boxes. One for departments and another for sections. The code is:

Route:

[image]

View fields:

[image]

Controller:

[image]

Javascript:

[image]

When I click in the first select I can get the related sections but the sections select doesn´t append. What am I doing wrong? I am implementing this solution with Laravel and SQL Server.

[image: 1st department]

[image: 2nd department]

All help is appreciated. Cheers, and keep up the good work :).

Answer (score 1):

After months of not having the opportunity to use Laravel I took some time to resolve this issue. I would like to have 3 comboboxes (Country, District, County) that were dependent for the country Portugal. The Solution I implemented is documented in the following images. If you have questions do not hesitate to ask. I know this is not the perfect solution but that's what I managed to get :). Thank you and keep up the good work.

Route:

```
//Listas (Distritos e Concelhos)
Route::get('/website/candidaturas/obterlistadistritos','Oportunidades\RecrutamentoController@obterListaDistritos');
Route::get('/website/candidaturas/obterlistaconcelhos','Oportunidades\RecrutamentoController@obterListaConcelhos');
```

View fields:

```
<label for="paisCandidatura">País</label>
<select onChange="" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('paisCandidatura') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" id="paisCandidatura" name="paisCandidatura">

<option value=""></option>
    @foreach($paises as $pais)
        @if($pais->id == old('paisCandidatura'))
            <option value="{{$pais->id}}" selected>{{$pais->nome}}</option>
        @else
            <option value="{{$pais->id}}">{{$pais->nome}}</option>
        @endif
    @endforeach

</select>
@if($errors->has('paisCandidatura'))
    <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $errors->first('paisCandidatura') }}</div>
@endif

<label for="distritoCandidatura">Distrito</label>
<select onChange="" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('distritoCandidatura') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" id="distritoCandidatura" name="distritoCandidatura">
    <option value =""></option>
    @if(old('paisCandidatura') == 141)

        @foreach($distritos as $distrito)

            @if($distrito->id == old('distritoCandidatura'))
                <option value="{{$distrito->id}}" selected>{{$distrito->nome}}</option>
            @else
                <option value="{{$distrito->id}}">{{$distrito->nome}}</option>
            @endif

        @endforeach

    @endif

</select>
@if($errors->has('distritoCandidatura'))
    <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $errors->first('distritoCandidatura') }}</div>
@endif

<label for="concelhoCandidatura">Concelho</label>
<select onChange="" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('concelhoCandidatura') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" id="concelhoCandidatura" name="concelhoCandidatura">
    <option value =""></option>
    @if(old('paisCandidatura') == 141)

        @foreach($concelhos as $concelho)

            @if($concelho->id == old('concelhoCandidatura'))
                <option value="{{$concelho->id}}" selected>{{$concelho->nome}}</option>
            @else
                <option value="{{$concelho->id}}">{{$concelho->nome}}</option>
            @endif

        @endforeach

    @endif

</select>
@if($errors->has('concelhoCandidatura'))
    <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $errors->first('concelhoCandidatura') }}</div>
@endif
```

Controller:

```
    /**
     * Return a list of districts associated to a country
     */
    public function obterListaDistritos(Request $request)
    {
        $distritos = Distrito::all()
        ->where("pais_id",$request->pais_id)
        ->pluck("nome","id");
        return response()->json($distritos);
    }

    /**
     * Return a lista of councils associated to a district
     */
    public function obterListaConcelhos(Request $request)
    {
        $concelhos = Concelho::all()
        ->where("distrito_id",$request->distrito_id)
        ->pluck("nome","id");
        return response()->json($concelhos);
    }
```

Javascript:

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#paisCandidatura').change(function(){
        var paisCandidatura = $(this).val();    
        if(paisCandidatura){
            $.ajax({
               type:"GET",
               url:"{{url('/candidaturas/obterlistadistritos')}}?pais_id="+paisCandidatura,
               success:function(res){               
                if(res){
                    $("#distritoCandidatura").empty();
                    $("#distritoCandidatura").append('<option value=""></option>');
                    $("#concelhoCandidatura").empty();
                    $("#concelhoCandidatura").append('<option value=""></option>');
                    $.each(res,function(key,value){
                        $("#distritoCandidatura").append('<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');
                    });
               
                }else{
                   $("#distritoCandidatura").empty();
                   $("#concelhoCandidatura").empty();
                }
               }
            });
        }else{
            $("#distritoCandidatura").empty();
            $("#concelhoCandidatura").empty();
        }      
       });
       
        $('#distritoCandidatura').on('change',function(){
        var distritoCandidatura = $(this).val();    
        if(distritoCandidatura){
            $.ajax({
               type:"GET",
               url:"{{url('/candidaturas/obterlistaconcelhos')}}?distrito_id="+distritoCandidatura,
               success:function(res){               
                if(res){

                    $("#concelhoCandidatura").empty();
                    $("#concelhoCandidatura").append('<option value=""></option>');
                    $.each(res,function(key,value){
                        $("#concelhoCandidatura").append('<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');
                    });
               
                }else{

                   $("#concelhoCandidatura").empty();

                }
               }
            });
        }else{

            $("#concelhoCandidatura").empty();
            
        }
            
       });
    </script>
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for hwo to write a proper answer. Please do not use images to display your code, but use markdown

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the warning. It's better this way? The negative vote was excused. Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 0):

To return json in laravel you should write

```
return response()
        ->json($seccoes);
```

I suggest you to use [eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent) it will make the code more readable maintain.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the response. I have made the alteration you suggested but with no luck. I get the response array, with the result sections, but the select stays empty. Can you please indicate an example with eloquent? I am still new to Laravel.

Comment: If I rewrite your code, you won't really learn Laravel I invite you to start here please https://laravel.com/ and I am sorry.

Comment: Apologies accepted. I just wanted to see a working example. Thank's anyway.